# LinuxBash does not open in the current folder

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

A long time ago I set up `Bash on Ubuntu on Windows`.
Now using Win10 when I'm in Explorer and right click in whitespace I can select
`Open LinuxBash Window from here`.

But the bash always opens at another default location.

What can I do to set the bash's path at the location I opened it from automatically?

Open Bash here:

[image]

But Bash is at "~":

[image]

EDIT:
I noticed when I type in `explorer.exe .` it does go back into the right folder, but when I check the possibilities after `cd` it shows completely different folders.

Comment: Never seen that type of option in context menu. Did you configured it yourself with registry?

Comment: Yes, this started showing after I went through some tutorial a long time ago

Comment: Well, what tutorial (in English)?  The directory for the Linux Subsystem for 1709.  Update your question, without knowing what you did, we cannot help.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, but if I knew what I did I could probably fix it myself, that's why I ask it here

Comment: You don’t know which tutorial you used?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, because it's such a long time ago and I'm not even sure if it was only one or if I looked a multiple ones at the same time.

Comment: One google search later -> https://www.windowscentral.com/how-launch-bash-shell-right-click-context-menu-windows-10

Comment: @Hannu You found it, that was the tutorial I went through I think!
But nevertheless it doesn't seem to work, because it's not opening in the folder I start it from as you can see in the screenshot, something is still wrong

Comment: Then; check whether you have the bash EXE in that exact location, and whether it is executable and has the right accessibility settings.

Comment: @Hannu Yes, the location seems correct - what the 'right' accessibility settings are I don't know exactly - but I attached a screenshot of my bash.exe in the question!

Comment: You need to change the registry key to include the current working directory, such as `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe $CWD` except I'm unsure what windows 10 uses to signify the cwd.

Comment: @djsmiley2k THAT WAS IT, THX! "$CWD" was missing! - post it as an answer and I accept :)

Comment: What?! That was partly a guess!!! Posted anyway ;)

Comment: @djsmiley2k a lucky guess than - when you mentioned it, I noticed that previously there was a "~" for whatever reason O.o...so maybe it would've also worked if I had just deleted that, but with your guess it works, so I'm done here :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the registry key to include the current working directory, such as `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe $CWD`

It will swap out $CWD to whatever directory you are running the command from.

Answer (score 1):

When using a shortcut you can just remove the `~` from the *Target* and add your wanted path to *Start in*. Example:

```
Target:     C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe
Start in:   C:\Users\Public
```

This will open a shell in:

```
your_username:/mnt/c/Users/Public$
```

Another possibility is to open the shell from within Windows Explorer where you are currently. This can be done with: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and then typing `bash`.

Last but not least, you could add a context-menu entry (e.g. `Bash On Ubuntu Here`) in Windows Explorer when right-clicking on a folder's background  by adding the following keys to the registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\bash_shell] 
@="Bash On Ubuntu Here"
"Icon"="%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\lxss\\bash.ico

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\bash_shell\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe\""
```